# React material-ui Expansion Panel width not constant in Chrome

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I've been facing this issue in chrome where the width changes to adapt to its content,
instead of occupying the width of the container,
On Firefox this is not seen

[image]

after clicking on the expand icon, it reduces its width like this,
This happens randomly sometimes, but usually on expanding or clicking on the contents of the expanded panel!
Any help will be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by adding style {flexGrow: 1} to the child of the ExpansionPanel, (I am using flex-box for styling layouts)